# VBA Simple Public Sub to Call Public Function

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to make this simple Function which exists only to call another function (it streamlines my code process). It gives me the error message:

> Compile error:
>
> Argument not optional

Here is the code (I have been working on this for about 2-3 weeks):

```
Public Sub Function32or16Bit()
Call Function4_ArrangeData1
End Sub
```

The first lines of Function4_ArrangeData1:

```
Public Sub Function4_ArrangeData1(ByRef pathAndFileName As String)

Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim isCellValueNull As Boolean
Dim DataRange As Variant
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

DataRange = Range(A1, Z200)
```

Comment: does Function4_ArrangeData1 expect any arguments (variables) to be sent to it?

Comment: @99moorem what do you mean? How would I check that?

Comment: look at the first line for Function4_ArrangeData1. should be something like Function Function4_ArrangeData1 () or function Function4_ArrangeData1 (ws,rng) variables could be different of course. If in doubt could you post the function Function4_ArrangeData1?

Comment: @99moorem the first lines of Function4_ArrangeData1 have been posted above. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try 

Function4_ArrangeData1("file path name string here")

Answer (score 0):

Your Function4_ArrangeData1 Sub requires that you pass in a string.

Change your call to include the path and file name either as a literal "C:\Temp\Temp.tmp" or string variable.

Or make the argument optional by typing OPTIONAL in front of the ByRef.

Or remove the argument from Public Sub Function4_ArrangeData1()